# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource while implementing spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, ldap

I've been trying to implement Spring security for LDAP Authentication in Java and I'm stuck here where it's not able to find bean of 'springSecurityFilterChain'.
Following is the error -

I'm getting following error -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 

creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class 
path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 
'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

I tried to google a lot about it, got to know a few things but not sure how to implement that.
Here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/jc.html
it says to implement following peace of code which will register this bean in Spring but not sure where exactly to put it.

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(WebSecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Also, this is config file where I'm trying to implement Spring security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import({ WebSecurityConfiguration.class })
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class})
public class LdapSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
        successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("/");
        http
        .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresInsecure().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login_form")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .failureUrl("/login_form?error")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login_form")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
        //http.addFilterBefore(new AuthTokenFilter(authenticationManager(), userDao), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(2).expiredUrl("/login_form");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer ldapConfig =
                auth.ldapAuthentication();
        ldapConfig.contextSource().url("ldap://ldap.vmware.com");
    
        ldapConfig.contextSource().managerDn("x");
        ldapConfig.contextSource().managerPassword("y");
        ldapConfig.userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})");
        ldapConfig.userSearchBase("dc=z, dc=com");
        ldapConfig.groupSearchBase(null);
        TokenAuthProvider provider = new TokenAuthProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }
}
```

Please giude me through!

Comment: I'm getting following error - 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: Please add the full exception stack trace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have figured out the issue, here it is -

Add below file under config folder of your spring boot project, so that it will get scanned while App startup and will create bean of springSecurityFilterChain.

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    
}
```

Along with above code, I was missing following dpendencies too,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I just had following dependency for ldap authentication using spring which wasn't sufficient even after adding AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now the issue which I had posted here has resolved by following above steps.

Cheers,